# different databases using CakePHP plugin Migration

Tags: cakephp, migration

I'm using plugin Migration from CakePHP and I have two databases in my app,

db1 (default)
tableX1
tableX2
tableX3
...
tableXn

db2
tableY1
tableY2
tableY3
...
tableYn

I want to run Migration that one part must be executed in db1 and other part in db2, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I'd setup different database configurations in your `app/Config/database.php`